# Android - user setting fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, setting

My user settings fragment does not work

It´s really simple - thus it should work.

Menu user settings -> onOptionsItemSelected-> new Intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, key) -> now it should use the fragment.xml.

- UserPreferencesFragment.java

  ```
  public class UserPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

      private static String SETTINGS_NAME_KEY = "name";
      private static String SETTINGS_EMAIL_KEY = "name";

      public static String getName(Context context) {
          return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(SETTINGS_NAME_KEY, "");
      }

      public static String getEmail(Context context) {
          return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(SETTINGS_EMAIL_KEY, "");
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          //adding the preferences from the xml
          //so this will in fact be the whole view.

          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
      }
  }
  ```

  XML file

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".......UserPreferencesActivity">


      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="@dimen/h1"
              android:text="@string/user_name" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/userName"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="@dimen/h1"
              android:text="" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:textSize="@dimen/h1"
              android:text="@string/user_email" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/userEmail"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="@dimen/h1"
              android:text="" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Now all should be well, but I get a massive exception which is posted in its whole.

```
03-26 11:42:58.584 31714-31714/xx.xx.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: xx.xx.xxxx, PID: 31714
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.xx.xxxx/xx.xx.xxxx.UserPreferencesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class resources
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class resources
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:443)
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:318)
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:264)
         at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:273)
         at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:301)
         at xx.xx.xxxx.UserPreferencesFragment.onCreate(UserPreferencesFragment.java:41)
         at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2198)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
         at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.preference.resources" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xx.xx.xxxx-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:376)
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:419)
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:318) 
         at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:264) 
         at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:273) 
         at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:301) 
         at xx.xx.xxxx.UserPreferencesFragment.onCreate(UserPreferencesFragment.java:41) 
         at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2198) 
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942) 
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
         at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.preference.resources
         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 26 more
      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root layout of your `prefs.xml` file must be `<PreferenceScreen>` not `<LinearLayout>`, you're using wrong file i guess

Comment: Yeahhh. Thx a lot. That just did the trick. No more exceptions here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment);
```

in onCreate() before you try to add your prefs I think.

Hope this helps